# Web scraping html tables in R

Tags: r, regex, web-scraping

I have a webpage: http://probabilityfootball.com/picks.html?1520027255&username=AVERAGES&weeknum=21

From the table on this site I am attempting to extract both teams, the winner, pick % and the score and then convert this information into a data frame.

I know I can combine greprexpr() and regmatches() to extract the information I need. I also know that each cell of the table starts with `<TD>` and ends with `</TD>`, but I need the information between these tags. So far I have:

```
library(rcurl)  
htmlCode <- getURL("http://probabilityfootball.com/picks.html?1520027255&username=AVERAGES&weeknum=21")  
data <- regmatches(htmlCode, grepexpr(pattern = "<TD>.+?</TD>))
```

However, this is returning a list with 29 different characters, and is no where close to what I want. I am not sure where to go from here.

If anyone has any input that'd be appreciated. If anyone posts code, I would benefit from it being as explicit as possible. Web scraping and using regular expressions are not my strong suits, and would like to understand the code and not just copy pasta it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Since the table structure is pretty messy, you may want to consider just reading that table as text first. Since I am assuming you will likely want to scrape multiple weeks, you may want to consider abstracting out the `weeknum` so that you can use it in a function:

```
library(rvest)
library(tidyverse)

base_url <- "http://probabilityfootball.com/picks.html"
username <- "AVERAGES"
weeknum <- "21"
full_url <- paste0(base_url, "?username=", username, "&weeknum=", weeknum)

page <- read_html(full_url)

table_text <- page %>%
  html_nodes("table") %>%
  .[5] %>%
  html_nodes("td") %>%
  html_text()

table_matrix <- matrix(table_text, ncol = 9, byrow = TRUE)

col_names <- c("deadline", "kickoff", "home_team_name", "home_team_score",
               "home_team_pick_pct", "score", "away_team_name", "away_team_score", "away_team_pick_pct")
colnames(table_matrix) <- col_names

result_df <- as_data_frame(table_matrix)
result_df
# # A tibble: 18 x 9
#   deadline     kickoff     home_team_name home_team_score  home_team_pick_… score  away_team_name away_team_score
#   <chr>        <chr>       <chr>          <chr>            <chr>            <chr>  <chr>          <chr>          
# 1 Sat, 12/29N… Sat, 12/29… New England    38               86%              79.40  N.Y. Giants    35             
# 2 Sun, 12/30N… Sun, 12/30… Buffalo        9                25%              60.03  Philadelphia   17             
# 3 Sun, 12/30N… Sun, 12/30… Carolina       31               41%              -62.20 Tampa Bay      23             
# 4 Sun, 12/30N… Sun, 12/30… Cincinnati     38               63%              24.52  Miami          25             
# 5 Sun, 12/30N… Sun, 12/30… Dallas         6                40%              8.05   Washington     27             
# 6 Sun, 12/30N… Sun, 12/30… Detroit        13               30%              46.40  Green Bay      34             
# 7 Sun, 12/30N… Sun, 12/30… Jacksonville   28               55%              -44.94 Houston        42
```

This approach will still require a bit of cleanup (e.g. any rows that do not start with a "day of week" such as 'tie breaker', 'regular season...' will need to be removed).